# OpenCV in Python error

Tags: python, opencv

When I run the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria in this, 30 max number of iterations, 0.001 minimum accuracy
# CV_TERMCRIT_ITER or CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, tells the algorithm that we want to terminate either after some number of iterations or when the convergence metric reaches some small value (respectively).
# The next two arguments set the values at which one, the other, or both of these criteria should terminate the algorithm.
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0), ..., (6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6), None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners2, ret)
        cv2.imshow('Img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

rms, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

I still get the following error:

```
runfile('D:/Isaac External/Master/Assignatures/CÀRREGA ÚTIL/Camera Calibration/Camera Calibration.py', wdir='D:/Isaac External/Master/Assignatures/CÀRREGA ÚTIL/Camera Calibration')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-3-dc33653bae3c>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('D:/Isaac External/Master/Assignatures/CÀRREGA ÚTIL/Camera 
Calibration/Camera Calibration.py', wdir='D:/Isaac External/Master/Assignatures/CÀRREGA ÚTIL/Camera Calibration')

File "C:\Users\Isaac\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Isaac\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "D:/Isaac External/Master/Assignatures/CÀRREGA ÚTIL/Camera Calibration/Camera Calibration.py", line 44, in <module>

error: ..\..\..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

The 14 jpg images that I'm loading were taken with an iPhone and can be opened with other programs without problems so the source of the issue does not seem to be the images.

Comment: Can you add a traceback with the error that you are getting?

Comment: You're passing an empty image to `imshow`. Do some debugging.

Comment: Its possible you are passing in a corrupted jpg file. In my case when I had this error, I was accidentally passing in a hidden file, and it caused this same error when running the resize function.

Comment: traceback added

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make sure that the `img` variable contains data for a valid image. You could print out the variable or check the [shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) of the image.

I would do it after

```
img = cv2.imread(fname)
```

and after

```
img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners2, ret)
```

When I had a similar error, I was reading in an image file that was corrupt.

Comment: Hi All, many thanks for your help, the jpg images are unmodified pictures taken with an iPhone 6 and can be loaded without problems in Irfanview or other windows so the images don't seem to be the problem.

Comment: In fact, if edit the source from:
    img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners2, ret)
to
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners2, ret)
the error does not pop up.

Comment: Seems like the function `cv2.grawChessboardCorners` has `None` return type. This explains why the error goes away when you do the latter instead. The function uses the `img` as the destination image.

Refer to this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Comment: EDIT: The previous comment had a typo, it should be `cv2.drawChessboardCorners`